# Link to homepage in Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I would like to know how can I insert a link to my homepage in my Flask app.

With other links I do something like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('quienes_somos') }}">Quienes Somos</a>
```

but since the url of my homepage is configured like this in my init.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I don't know how to reference it. I've tried like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('') }}">Inicio</a>
<a href="{{ url_for('/') }}">Inicio</a>
```

but both ways throw error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `url_for('index')` as that is the name of the function you are decorating (and the function or method's `__name__` is what is used for `endpoint` unless you specify the `endpoint` argument to `route` explicitly).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use a Jinja directive for this task. Simply add a link to the *'/'* route like this:

```
<a href="/">Inicio</a>
```

Comment: Yes this would work, but the link would break if he decides to change the index page to something else e.g `/home`. So it's safter and better to use a Jinja directive that would always be aware of the link